# No jquery Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am going to create a multi dropdown menu with pure javascript and css . so i think like that :

[image]

So I will create a 5 div (columns) which every column has 4 rows(think like matrix) . and I will move down the Item2-1,Item2-2,Item2-3 . is it correct ? what is the best way to create dropdown like this ? I want that works in any browser.

Comment: relative positioning or absolute ?

Comment: You may want to attempt this yourself first, then ask (perhaps on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)) if there is a better way. I would recommend using a list though instead of divs.

Comment: Google is always a good solution... http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: I had done something similar , but there is no good event

Comment: styling this example you can do what you want. what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pure CSS solution from Stu Nichols. No JS needed.

http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html